# Python variable manipulated indirectly without being mentioned in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

I'm a coding beginner that's putting a project together for a game. To update the game board, I use this function:

```
Board = [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
def boardupdate(self, move):
    for index, val in enumerate(move):
        try:
            if val >= 15:
                val -= 3
                move[index] = val
        except TypeError:
            pass
    try: self[move[0]] = 1
    except Exception: None
    try: self[move[1]] = 0
    except Exception: None
    try: self[move[2]] = 0
    except Exception: None
    return self
```

Where the first item of the list `move` represents the location where a piece is being placed in a turn, the second item representing where the piece is being taken from (in this game, you can either place a new piece on the board or move a piece), and the third item represents where a piece is being completely removed from the game. A certain turn can involve any of or none of these actions, hence the `try` and `except` blocks (which I learned just today, so if I am using them incorrectly, help would be much appreciated).

The code works as intended inside the function, but for some reason after this function is called, `Board` gets changed as if it was run through the function.

```
print(Board)
print(boardupdate(Board, [0, None]))
print(Board)
```

returns:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I've tried to solve this by copying `Board` to a temporary variable like so:

```
def boardupdate(self, move):
    tempboard = self
    for index, val in enumerate(move):
        try:
            if val >= 15:
                val -= 3
                move[index] = val
        except TypeError:
            pass
    try: tempboard[move[0]] = 1
    except Exception: None
    try: tempboard[move[1]] = 0
    except Exception: None
    try: tempboard[move[2]] = 0
    except Exception: None
    return tempboard
```

Returns the same output as before. How can I change the output of this function without messing around with the initial conditions of `Board`? This is necessary in order for the rest of my code to run. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't use exceptions for normal flow control, `if .. elif .. else` are intended for that purpose. `try .. except` are useful for catching exceptions and that helps if you're catching the exception in some place that's not known or accessible to the code causing it, or when the cause is a surprise - in situations like yours the overhead of an exception is not worth it, since you get no more value from it than a simple `if`. Your problem however is that assigning a mutable like this object to a variable like `tempboard` doesn't copy it, it and `self` are just assigned the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tempboard = board` doesn't copy `board`, it just binds `tempboard` to the same value as `board`.  If you do:

```
tempboard = board.copy()
```

it will actually copy `board`.

Some other miscellaneous advice on this function:

- Don't call the board parameter `self`, since this isn't an instance method on the board itself.  Just call it something like `board`.
- Don't catch all exceptions blindly; it makes errors very difficult to debug.  If you have an error in your code, you *want* it to raise an exception so you can see exactly what went wrong right away, rather than spending hours trying to figure out why it's just not doing anything!  I'd suggest adopting a convention that a move you aren't making is `None`, and then checking for `None` specifically, rather than just ignoring any attempted move that raises an exception.
- Use named variables and/or comments to keep track of what the different `move` items represent.

```
def boardupdate(board, move):
    board = board.copy()
    # Subtract 3 from any move positions >= 15.
    move = [p if p is None or p < 15 else p - 3 for p in move]

    [moved_to, moved_from, removed] = move
    if moved_to is not None:
        board[moved_to] = 1
    if moved_from is not None:
        board[moved_from] = 0
    if removed is not None:
        board[removed] = 0

    return board
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just pointing to `Board`, not actually copying it. In python, iterables are not copied by default for efficiency reasons.
So for example:

```
x=[1,2,3]
y=x
y[1]=5
print(x)
[1,5,3]
```

To get over this, you should make a deep copy of `Board` either inside the function:

```
tempboard = self.copy()
```

or when you are calling the function:

```
boardupdate(Board.copy())
```

This is not the same for immutable objects, like integers:

```
x=5
y=x
y+=1
print(x)
5
```

Comment: The behavior of variable binding isn't different between integers and lists.  The difference is that with integers you can *only* rebind the variable to a new object, you can't mutate the object itself (i.e. you can't do `x[0] = 1` to mutate one of x's bits, you can only rebind `x` to a different integer entirely).